# Excel Matches value and fetch

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax

I am working on an excel simple query, where I am trying to fetch `Name` based on first if the `ID` matches, and second if the `Status` column has a value of `Pick`, else Nothing

Table 2

```
ID.    Name
1001   Chris
1002   Leoe
1003   Nyle
```

Table 1

```
ID.    Status
1001   Pick
1002    No
1003   Pick
1004   Pick
```

Expected result

```
ID.    Status.  Name
1001   Pick     Chris
1002    No     
1003   Pick     Leoe
1004   Pick
```

I am trying this query but something is wrong here -

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH([ID];Table2[ID];0));IF([Status]="Pick";Table2[Name];""))
```

But I am getting this error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7HAI.png)

Can anyone help me to solve this problem!

Comment: Surely in the expected results, it should be Nyle (ID 1003) not Leoe (ID 1002)?

Comment: Please check your post. The headers you give for the tables are "ID." and "Status." not "ID" and "Status" ... is this a typo? Also, is it intended that Table2 has fewer rows than Table1 (ie no ID=1004 entry), or is this a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tables and results are laid as per:

[image]

Then, there are two formulas I'd use for

1. Status
   **=INDEX($D$2:$D$5,MATCH($E2,$C$2:$C$5,0))**
2. Name
   **=IF($F2="No","",IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$4,MATCH($E2,$A$2:$A$4,0)),""))**

Note: Name is restricted to the 3 you've identified in table 1. Also, ID 1003 is for Nyle and not Leoe